# How do you handle AWS Cognito newPasswordRequired from VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cognito

I'm reading through the [AWS Amplify docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/vue) particularly the VueJS portions and I'm wondering how a typical VueJS project handles a newPasswordRequired challenge. I have read through a tutorial on Medium as well as a tutorial on Dev.to and neither address this. It's been challenging to find walk through.

I notice that a lot of the work flows, like sign in, sign in, sign out, forgot password, you name it, all have VueJS components in the library. I'm wondering if I've missed something idiomatic because this seems like a very common workflow.

I can just roll my own component and model or page to direct the user to and send in the challenge. The [authentication docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication) seem to off load this to me in the form of a call to the non-existent "getInformationFromUser()" call. It seems like this is something that there would be a common VueJS component in the library for. just given how much else is also there. Have I missed something?